# How to make this kind of structure in android to be sent to firebase firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I was using this structure

```
public class NewVendor
{
    public String title;


    public Map<String,String> array;

    public NewVendor(String title, Map<String, String> array) {
        this.title = title;
        this.array = array;
    }
}

Map<String,String> list = new HashMap<>();
        list.put("Vendor Name",newVendorName);
        list.put("Vendor Address",newVendorAddress);

        NewVendor newVendor = new NewVendor(newVendorName,list);

        db.collection("Bills").document(firebaseUser.getUid()).set(newVendor)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(AddNewBillActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(AddNewBillActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

But it is not working.It is overriding the last saved data but I want to add the latest object. ArrayList is not permitted in Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to update an existing document, so should call `update`. This requires that you specify what fields of the document you want to update, in your case the `newVendorName`:

```
Map<String,Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
updates.put(newVendorName, newVendor);
        db.collection("Bills").document(firebaseUser.getUid()).update(updates)...
```

For more on this, read the [Firestore documentation on updating fields in nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).